# How do you retrofit a recessed light with no slots in can?

Tags: wiring, recessed-lighting

I'm trying to replace all of my recessed lights with LED retrofit kits but after removing the baffle there don't appear to be any slots in the can for the springs of the LED kit (The baffle was attached by a spring clip at the bulb socket).

Any idea what I should do here? I do see on Amazon they sell some clips that can be screwed into the side of the can but ami missing something?  I tried just pushing them in and they stay up but they don't really get flush with the ceiling.

[image]

Comment: You either need a retrofit trim that mounts differently (such as the "three-blade" style that rotate to lock/unlock by jam fitment of hinged blades) or you need to retrofit the spring clips. I'd start with looking very closely at the sides of your cans in case they have spring clips pre-die-cut but not folded/bent out into position - that would be a stroke of luck, but not unthinkable.

Comment: Looks like you might have a lip of drywall mud keeping them from getting flush.

Comment: Can you post a manufacturer and model number or picture of the kit you chose? I had one LED kit that had springs which press-fit into the ridges of the existing can ring, and the other lights I converted I used flood-light-shape LED bulbs.

Comment: I use spring clips that hold the new lamp in place in the can with the spring force some only have 2 arms some have 3 for me mounting the driver is usually the challenge as my drivers are not part of the light element. There are different sizes make sure you have the correct diameter retro kit.

Comment: Here is an example of a "three blade" style light: [three blade retention](https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/81fcb0ac-3b5d-4223-9f93-f418292cc6b3/svn/commercial-electric-recessed-lighting-trims-53804101-1f_1000.jpg). The problem is that its hard to shop for a light by its retention style.

Comment: I have a thought, but I'd have to see a pic of what your retrofit looks like to know if it would have a chance of working. Pics of the replacement from the top and the side would help immensely.

Comment: look for "torsion spring clip" or "torsion spring hook" on amazon or similar - you'll find packs of these with self-tapping screws so you can add your own spring clips inside the can. will need a 90-degree attachment for your impact driver to put the screws in the can.